# Why isn't Modernizr working for me?

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I don't think modernizr likes me, can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong. I can't seem to get modernizr to work on firefox, ie etc... I'm only using elements like header, footer and nav...

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 lte9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="notie no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <script src="modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/kmy1sfb.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

  </head>
```

Checking firebug it outputs fine, I get all of the elements i'm supposed to but none of the elements are working...

For example if I click header in firebug and edit the CSS height to 5000px it doesn't move, also the alignment etc isn't correct.

Comment: Check with Firebug, under the script panel can you find the modernizr lib listed?

Comment: Don't know, could be a number of things... Try re-downloading modernizer and re-including it. Do you perhaps have an online example of this?

Comment: Maybe try to refresh your browser cache.

Comment: If you're using all those parts, you should also use the excellent html5boilerplate.com css to go with it! It already has the solution below baked in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably are forgetting to style the new HTML5 elements as block-level elements. By default, browsers treat any unknown element as an inline element (`display:inline`) which makes it difficult to do much with them.

Newer browsers are slowly treating the new HTML5 elements as stable, meaning they start giving them default styling like `display:block` for the `header` element, for instance. But, most browsers on the market today don’t have those default styles for HTML5 elements, so you’ll need to provide them.

Here’s a quick sample bit of CSS to do that:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
```

Adding that CSS to your main.css should fix your styling issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was trying to use a CDN and it wasn't working (I might have had the wrong link). The test I found was to put

```
.borderradius body {
  background: #c00;
}
```

in your main.css and see if the background turns red. If it is modernizr, is working.

EDIT: I've also found that the script must be inserted at the top of the HTML document. Putting it at the bottom, as suggested for better loading speed of pages, doesn't work.