# Make HTML5 header work with IE — HTML5 Shiv doesn’t fix my layout

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, dom

I posted the other day about problems I was having with my layout in IE.

Today I figured out my problem, IE was not working for my HTML5 elements like `<header>` and `<footer>`

When I replaced them with `<div>` almost all my problems went away.  So I started searching for how to add IE suppot for these HTML5 features.

I came across [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [HTML5 Shiv](http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js) also from what I read, the basic Javascript to add support for something like `<header>` is this...

```
document.createElement("header");
```

Now you can see I have done my research and I am still not having any luck.  Modernizr did not work so then I tried the HTML Shiv trick and still no luck so then on to the Javascript trick and no luck either.

So please can someone tell me what I can do?

My IE version is 8 and sorry I do not have a live version of the site to show

Comment: It helps if you mention what the problems are...

Comment: Can you post your source, I'm assuming your question is, " I did this HTML5 layout but it's not working on IE, why?"

Comment: I guess that you are adding these html5 elements via ajax, right?

Comment: @Wojciech Bednarski why do you think that?

Comment: Because after each ajax call you have to register these elements in DOM again. I cannot see any other problems why it doesn't work for you...

Comment: Ah, wait do you know that these elements by default have `display: inline` under IE? Try to change it to `display: block`. If you can provide some code, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625433/why-isnt-modernizr-working-for-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those scripts will make the new elements work in IE but their display style is still missing.
Add the following css which I copy pasted from html5boilerplate.com:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
```