# How to make CSS for HTML5 <header> work properly in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm working with a website and everything looks good except the one issue with the #nav-wrapper. In IE it's all the way to the right. That said, it's floated right but floated right of the #nav-wrapper which is a set width which is then placed in the header which is a set width. So I'm not sure why it's all the way to the right. This is a wordpress website soI've simplified the menu and banner, etc. [This is the site.](http://thestuffedpepper.ca)

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
<header>
       <div id="nav-wrapper">
       <span class="nav-swirl-top">The Stuffed Pepper, Summerland BC</span>
        <nav id="access" role="navigation">
            MENU LIST
        </nav><!-- #access -->


           <div id="nav-updates">
        <p>Updates</p>
        </div>


            <span class="nav-swirl-bottom">The Stuffed Pepper</span>            
    </div><!-- #nav-wrapper -->


    <div id="banner">
       <img src="http://www.mysite.com/img/banner1.png" alt="Banner 1">'
    </div>

</header>
</div>

<div id="main">
<div id="container">


#header-wrapper { width: 100%; height: 532px; background: url(img/header-bg.jpg) repeat-x;}
header { clear: both; height: 620px; width: 900px;}
#banner { position: absolute; top: 230px; width:700px; left: 50%; margin-left: -470px; z-index: 1; }
#nav-wrapper { position: relative; clear: both; width: 252px; height: 365px; padding: 10px; float: right; margin-top: 230px;background-color: #650908; border: 1px solid #470604;}
#container { clear: both; background: url(img/container-bg.jpg) repeat; border-bottom: 3px solid #9d1316; color: #ccc1a1; }
```

Here's what it's looking like.
[image]

So if I have a set width and height for the #header-wrapper now, why is my test showing up under it as well?? Just not sure what IE likes to do and how it chooses to ignore styles!

I appreciate any help.

UPDATE

Not sure why it shows the header not closed properly..

[image]

This is what it actually looks like.
I see that the `</hgroup/>` looks like that for you but not for me at all.

Even with the firefox developer tools it shows correctly
[image]

Comment: your link just goes to the construction.html page.

Comment: Sorry, try again. I fixed that

Comment: @ambrelasweb, Currently, your webpage is offline. Was an acceptable answer found or do you have a new test page link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all HTML5 tags work / are supported by Internet explorer, especially older versions.

See this [reference article](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/).

There are number of ways to try and make things work for IE:

- Use [HTML5 Shiv](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/)
- Use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com)
- See [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350341/make-html5-header-work-with-ie-html5-shiv-doesnt-fix-my-layout)
- Use a [jQuery solution](http://www.splashnology.com/article/html-5-in-internet-explorer/395/)

Also inspect the site using IE's developer tools. It appears that the `header` HTML is not opened and closed properly. Look:

[image]

Comment: I've not had any problem with the <header> tag in IE7 with other websites though.

Comment: Unless you're using a library like modernizr or html5shiv, html5 tags like `header` are not reliable in IE8 and earlier.

Comment: Hmm...I thought I had something in there, it was from the TwentyTen them, but I just pointed it to the online version of the shiv and it worked. Could you tell me why my container is under my banner still?

Comment: That would be a good reason why it wasn't working however I don't see that happening in either the wordpress editor or firefox developer tools. See updated question.

Comment: I also see a bunch of CSS and Javascript inside the `<header>` you should put your CSS all in one place inside the `<head>` tag and move all your JavaScript to the bottom just before the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @ambrelasweb: But it's IE you're having issues with.

Comment: I don't have a choice where all the css goes sometimes as the plugins I download for my wordpress them place them there. But that still wont help out why my #container is underneath my banner..

Comment: @ambrelasweb, Currently, your webpage is offline. Was an acceptable answer found or do you have a new test page link?