# Used HTML Shiv, but still not able to display the Header content in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla, internet-explorer-6, html5shiv

I have used Joomla 3.3 to develop a website. HTML5 Shiv was there for recognition of HTML5 elements. But still not able to view the contents under "Header" tag in IE6.

Please refer the HTML5 Shiv [3.6.2pre](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/releases/tag/3.6.2pre) code.

Answer (score 0):

There are other questions on StackOverflow that ask very similar things. Have you tried the suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350629/436641 for example?

Given what (at the time of writing this answer) is in the question, there is nearly nothing to go on. One thing, though, is that the version of HTML5 Shiv being used is an old one (3.6.2pre from February 2013). Update to 3.7.2 (from May 2014) and see if that fixes the issue.

Beyond that, it would be much easier to help solve the problem if the question included your HTML code and other relevant code of yours.

Comment: I Have tried this solution "http://stackoverflow.com/a/8350629/436641" by appending the code at the end of my HTML Shiv file.That solved problem in IE 6, but my IE8 look becomes disastrous.