# HTML 5 elements not working in IE 7 with modernizr

Tags: html, modernizr

I can't get the html 5 elements working in IE 7 using modernizr here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/xmJaf/)

Dont know what I am doing wrong works in IE 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since HTML5 is getting more attention by way of marking up our new pages, and the only way to get IE to acknowledge the new elements, such as , is to use the HTML5 shiv, I’ve quickly put together a mini script that enables all the new elements.

Download html5shiv.js(https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/) and must be inserted in the head element (this is because IE needs to know about the element before it comes to render them – so it can’t sit in the footer of the page, i.e. below the elements in question).

EDIT 1

With IE, even with the shiv, you need to declare the HTML 5 elements as block elements. I use this line for Internet Explorer, but you can modify it for the elements you need.

```
header,nav,article,footer,section,aside,figure,figcaption{display:block}
```

From the [Modernizr Documentation](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie): "you’ll also probably want to set many of these elements to display:block;"

Comment: I thought that modernizr contains this shiv?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. In modernizr's documents it says that i contains the Shiv. Which is why I don't understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: did you try with the html5shiv.js?

Comment: yeah and it still doesn't work, I am using IE developer tools to test, do these render in IE 7 correctly?

Comment: refere these links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625433/why-isnt-modernizr-working-for-me   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855294/html5shiv-vs-dean-edwards-ie7-js-vs-modernizr-which-to-choose     http://modernizr.com/docs/

Comment: I have the elements set to display block, its in the myer html 5 reset

Comment: have a look at the  Modernizr Documentation

Comment: Thank you I have been reading it just can't understand where I have gone wrong

Comment: Just so the rest of the community knows what a muppet I have been, the reason it didn't look like it was working in IE 7 is that I was using outline whilst making my layout, of course I just remembered IE 7 doesn't support it. Don't I feel the fool

Comment: did the battel comes to the end?

Comment: yes thank you, a school boy error on my part, it was working all along. That you Satish for your help