# Modernizr not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, modernizr

apologies in advance if this is a silly question, but I did have a look around and couldn't find what I needed.

Basically I'm new to Modernizr, but I'm seeing what I need to in Mozilla - either view source or F12 for dev tools and I see a class on the html tag with a list. I can't see this in IE or Chrome, though. What silly mistake am I making? I'm happy to post a link to the test page.

Thanks!
MK

EDIT

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js"><!-- modernizr detection 1 -->
<head>
<title>stuff</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]--><!-- allows older browsers (IE) to support modern html5 elements -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('#pull');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

<link href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli|Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><!-- fonts to use -->
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- modernizr detection 2 -->

</head>
<body>
<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625433/why-isnt-modernizr-working-for-me-->

        <script>
        if (!Modernizr.borderradius) {
            $.getScript("jquery.corner.js", function () {
                $("#cornerDiv").corner();
            });
        }
    </script>



<div class="container">


    <!--HEADER-->
    <header class="row">
        <div class="columns three">

            <div class="logo-search">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="logo" />

                <div class="search"><p>Search</p></div>

                <div class="quote"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-social">

    <nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#" title="Skip">Skip</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    </nav>


                <div class="social-top"><p><img src="images/facebook-btn.png" alt="" />FACEBOOK <img src="images/twitter-btn.png" alt="" />TWITTER <img src="images/pinterest-btn.png" alt="" />PINTEREST</p></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
    <!--/HEADER-->

    <!--MAIN CONTENT-->
        <div class="row1">

            <div class="columns one">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Dolar Sit Amet...</h1>

                <div>
                <p>
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu ugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat dproident, sunt in 
                culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim (more).</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="columns two">
                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    <!--/MAIN CONTENT-->

</div><!--/container -->    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 and below did not show a live DOM preview in the developer tools. You'll have to click the refresh button located at the top-left of the DOM Explorer in IE10. Chrome should show live updates. Can you share your code, or a link to your project?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I have added the code to my post, if you could take a quick look that would be brilliant, thanks. From what you've said, I think it must be down to what I've done, possibly I've placed things in the wrong order.

Comment: You won't see Modernizr in view-source, since that will show the downloaded markup, rather than the generated DOM representation. You'll have to look in the DOM Explorer itself.

Comment: Can you share a few more details with me? I just launched your code in IE11 and it appears to work properly. Here are my developer tools http://i.imgur.com/U4whKsq.png.

Comment: FYI: modernizr is also a html5 shiv, so load only one, & modernizr should be the first script you load, before anything else.

Comment: Hi both, thank you very much for your help and apologies for the late response. I took on your info, eliminated the html5 shiv, updated to IE11 and make sure to load modernizr first of all and now I'm seeing everything in IE just fine. Thank you so much for your help with this!