# Modernizr isn't working for "column-count" in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, modernizr

I added reference to Modernizr JS file and put `class="no-js"` in `html` tag.

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="App_Themes/MetroTouchCountries/TabStrip.MetroTouchCountries.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.61385.js"></script>
</head>
```

I'm using `column-count` property in one of CSS classes:

```
.listWithFlags {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    font-family: Calibri, Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:13px;
    display: block;
}
```

It looks good on Chrome, Firefox, IE 10+ but **doesn't work in IE9.**

I see that `no-js` is replaced with a longer code in the browser so I think JS reference is correct. I also added `display: block` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625433/why-isnt-modernizr-working-for-me). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internet Explorer 9 and below do not support [`column-count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772195(v=vs.85).aspx); support wasn't added until version 10. It's important to remember that Modernizr primarily exists to help you know what the browser is capable of, and not to make the browser capable of more. [It does this via special classes added to the document, and the presence of a global `Modernizr` object for scripting purposes](http://modernizr.com/docs/#whatis).

If you would like to support CSS Columns in Internet Explorer 9, you'll need to do so via another route. I would suggest [jQuery Columnizer](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin) as I've used it in the past, and it should come across as fairly familiar to anybody versed in CSS Column syntax:

```js
$( "html.no-csscolumns .listWithFlags" ).columnize( { columns: 3 } );
```

Basing the selector on the presence of `.no-csscolumns` would result in this script *only* running in versions of Internet Explorer prior to 10. Alternatively, you could use that global object from earlier:

```
if ( !Modernizr.csscolumns ) {
    $( ".listWithFlags" ).columnize( { columns: 3 } );
}
```

Whichever makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks. Now trying to use Columnizr with Modernizr. I have another issue. I'd appreciate if you have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680551/trying-to-use-jquery-columnizr-plugin-object-doesnt-support-property-or-met

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because IE9 doesn't support `column-count` property. See [Can I Use - column-count](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count).

I think you are misreading into what Modernizr actually does. It does not give you support for features the browser doesn't have (It does provide support for a few HTML5 elements though). Taken directly from [Modernizr's Documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

> what Modernizr does is, very simply, tell you whether the current browser has this feature natively implemented or not.