# Trying to use jQuery Columnizr plugin: "Object doesn't support property > or method 'columnize'"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, multiple-columns

I'm trying to use jQuery Columnizr plugin. Here is my code (simplified, full version is in screenshot)

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="App_Themes/MetroTouchCountries/TabStrip.MetroTouchCountries.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.columnizer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Use this script to support CSS3 multi column feature in IE 7, 8, 9 -->
    <script src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.61385.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.sutunlar').columnize({ columns: 3 });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
```

This is the error I get:

> Unhandled exception at line 29, column 13 in http:/xx/
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'columnize'

[image]

Comment: Can you ensure that Columnizer is being loaded? (Use F12's Network tool) Make sure the JavaScript file is not missing, or is not malformed in any way (this can happen when downloading .js files from GitHub, for instance).

Comment: Good point but didn't work. F12 says that file is loaded. I've downloaded it again. Also tried to use CDN (//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.columnizer/1.6.0/jquery.columnizer.js). The same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is **ScriptManager** in `<body>` (Sorry that I didn't include `<body>` in my question). jquery and bootstrap definitions were conflicting with my script references in `<head>`. I commented out two lines in ScriptManager and the problem went away.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <%-- <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" /> --%>
            <%-- <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" /> --%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```